# Hazelcast fails to load map with "large" number of entries

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am having an issue with Hazelcast when trying to load a map with over 40000 entries.

Hazelcast loads the map fine if I limit the number of entries to roughly 40000. Much more than that results in the following exception getting thrown repeatedly. I am using a Hazelcast MapLoader. MapLoader.getAllKeys executes successfully regardless of result size. The exception is thrown for each batch of objects to be loaded.
I am using Hazelcast version 3.7.2 with a single node. Any help or guidance greatly appreciated.

```
09-Dec-2016 12:38:19.885 WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-3] com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.null Exception occurred
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:85)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:186)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.executeWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:326)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.waitWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:310)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.waitWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:284)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.waitUntilLoaded(MapProxySupport.java:583)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.waitUntilLoaded(MapProxyImpl.java:82)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.initializeMapStoreLoad(MapProxySupport.java:225)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.initialize(MapProxySupport.java:217)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.initialize(MapProxyImpl.java:82)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.ProxyRegistry.doCreateProxy(ProxyRegistry.java:180)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.ProxyRegistry.createProxy(ProxyRegistry.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.ProxyRegistry.getOrCreateProxy(ProxyRegistry.java:139)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.ProxyServiceImpl.getDistributedObject(ProxyServiceImpl.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.getDistributedObject(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:372)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.getMap(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:178)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceProxy.getMap(HazelcastInstanceProxy.java:92)
    at com.df.repository.hazelcast.MapFactory.getOrCreateMap(DataFabricMapFactory.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.InternalPartitionServiceImpl.getPartitionId(InternalPartitionServiceImpl.java:834)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoaderUtil$2.apply(MapKeyLoaderUtil.java:113)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoaderUtil$2.apply(MapKeyLoaderUtil.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.util.IterableUtil$2.next(IterableUtil.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoaderUtil.nextBatch(MapKeyLoaderUtil.java:86)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoaderUtil$1.next(MapKeyLoaderUtil.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoaderUtil$1.next(MapKeyLoaderUtil.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader.sendKeysInBatches(MapKeyLoader.java:309)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader.access$200(MapKeyLoader.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader$1.call(MapKeyLoader.java:192)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader$1.call(MapKeyLoader.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:67)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:111)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrow(InvocationFuture.java:74)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code to replicate the issue?What's the size of the objects you are storing?

Comment: The objects are not large. Just simple pojo with half a dozen string properties. Providing sample code could be difficult. But this is a spring configured map.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ONE of those 80000 records had a null id. My fault for assuming that the column would be NOT NULL. After removing the bad data, all seems to be working well.